# Can not paying a monthly fee because of a lack of balance of your reloadable visa card hurt your credit score and isn't there a law against that?

Tags: contract-law, canada, consumer-protection

Can not paying a monthly fee because of a lack of balance of your reloadable visa card hurt your credit score and isn't there a law against that?

That's what I was told after I bought a visa debit card. Is this something new? I thought there was a monthly fee only if there was a remaining balance on my card. Isn't there a law against such practice in Canada? I bought the card in Canada and card companies used to not slap you with a negative balabce when you bought a reloadable debit card, but I guess everything goes nowadays.

Comment: Is this a monthly fee related to the card itself? Or from an outside source? Also, what do you mean by "buying a reloadable visa debit card"? Is this a secured card, or a visa gift card? (If unsure: Did you sign a contract with a bank, etc. or did you buy it in e.g. a supermarket? Does it have your name printed on the front?)

Comment: It's a Canada Post Reloadable Visa Card, with monthly usage fees. Bought it at a pharmacy, it doesn't have my name on it, but I had to register for it just now.

Comment: I'm not sure how a reloadable card, acquired anonymously, *could possibly* affect your credit rating.  When you registered the card, did you supply your Canadian SSN-equivalent?  Same name/same address could be your son/father. And someone registering a reloadable card does not make them the account holder, they might just be the person placing funds in it.  E.G. if you are the trustor of an incompetent person, you might use a reloadable card like that to dole out "walking-around money" on a daily basis etc.

Comment: I would refer to the T&Cs of the card - this is going to be a normal scenario for them, and they might simply do something like suspend the card when the fee hasnt been paid etc.